# How can I delete duplicates in two different csv files for a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two csv files and both have a common column named 'Name'. How can I compare the two and write a new file without the duplicate values?

Code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df1 = pd.read_csv('Stale1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Stale2.csv')

list1=df1['Name'].tolist()
list2=df2['Name'].tolist()
```

Example of the columns:

```
Name
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

```
Name
aaa
vvv
hhh
```

I would like to write a new file that does not contain 'aaa' as it is the duplicate.
Desired output:

```
Name
bbb
ccc
ddd
vvv
hhh
```

Comment: something with `df1.merge(df2, on='Name')`?

Comment: would this work if the columns were not the same length in the files?

Comment: Do `df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='outer', indicator=True)` and look for `_merge` value different than `'both'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the two dataframes and then use the [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep=False, ignore_index=True)
```

where `subset='Name'` tells to consider only the column `'Name'` for identifying duplicates and `keep=False` tells to drop all the duplicates.

To get the final result use:

```
df['Name'].tolist()
```

Comment: how do i get it to only return the name column though?

Comment: @pythonscrub Just put `['Name']` at the end.